# Help center "contact" page refers to old top bar "help" link

Tags: feature-request, help-center, contact

On the `/contact` page of sites, the introduction still refers to the old top bar which had a "help" button:

> [image: If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on Meta Stack Exchange or the site's own meta. (Look under "help" on the top bar.)]
>
> If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on Meta Stack Exchange or the site's own meta. (Look under "help" on the top bar.)

The old one used to look like:

> [image: Old topbar 'help' dropdown link]

but now it's just a question mark.

Can `Look under "help" on the top bar.` be changed to something along the lines of `Look under the question mark button on the top bar`?

Or, even better could that text automatically link to the current site's Meta, or a link to the `/help/whats-meta` of the current site, rather than relying on the user to find the link under the dropdown, as there are quite a few links there:

[image]

Flipping the order of that sentence to suggest asking on the site's own meta *first* might also be useful.